# Which should control the design of application software, Language or Framework or Domain?

Tags: design, design-patterns, application-design

Recently i have been looking more into the design part of application programs. The suggestion seems to be very different across different sources. For example the books like code complete suggest to build into language or framework. Other approach like clean will suggest a more business or domain driven approach.

Which will be the approach which can put our self at a competitive advantage on a long term base? Especially i will like to know how it applies in mobile app development.

Answer (score 2):

*Option 4: **None of the above.***

The advice to "build to a language/framework" is orthogonal to DDD - you should do both; this isn't an either/or situation.  Well-designed software should be modular with clean separation between layers; this way you can achieve both.

Top-layer UI modules shouldn't be concerned about dealing with business logic or domain logic;  they should be focused on providing the user with a great workflow and UX - it's design should be informed by UI framework best practices along with common UI design patterns such as MVC/MVVM/MVP/etc.

Domain layer modules should know nothing about the UI or UX, but instead focus on business logic - its design should be driven by domain requirements.

Clean separation between your UI/App layer and your Business/Domain layer involves interface(s) separating the two; there's no reason for the design of a UI to affect the domain model or business logic, and the implementation of business logic has no reason to affect or constrain the design or implementation of a UI.

Furthermore, there's no reason necessarily why your UI should even use the same programming language as your domain layer - for example, a UI using HTML+ECMAScript and a Business Layer using a server-side technology such as ASP.NET or Ruby on Rails; in which case there will be minimal overlap between the two aside from a REST interface.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question.

Comment: @MartinMaat could you elaborate on that?  The question implies to me that it's asking whether DDD concerns should override concerns about the app framework, which seems like a false-choice to me.

Comment: I jumped to conclusions after reading your answer diagonally and spotting general design advice. After reading it better I actually agree with it. I had to mess with it a bit (removed a double "the") before I could cancel out my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Despite all the clean theory, typically some architectural choices precede the design choices made in the context of a particular project or application. This means you will have to deal with a number of givens that may not necessarily be the best choices for the project/application you are building. Think an RDBMS, an OS, a particular programming language.

These baseline tools were designed for a particular (range of) problem domain(s). As long as you develop solutions within the target domains of the tools, they will help you with build-in patterns.

So in any given environment, some design patterns will be fixed upfront. As the architectural choices once made get outdated and/or the business evolves, you may start to experience some strain in your modeling experience. You may want to do things one way while your tools are insisting to do things another way.